# how to store data entered in TextInput widget into json using kivy and python

Tags: android, python, kivy

can anyone show me a simple example of how to store user input('TextInput' widget) data into json using kivy and python.

Answer (score 2):

The [Kivy Storage](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.storage.html) module is probably the easiest way. There's an example of storing strings in the docs. You would just retrieve the string from your TextInput like myinput.text